# How can I get a match demo that I can't download?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been away from the game for a few months and I remember a match where I had a 2K one round and I downloaded the match again, but now I cannot download my game to watch later. The only thing I can view is the scoreboard of that match.

Is there a way I can download the demo? It doesn't have download as an option when I right-click the on the match.

Comment: I get that you're trying to be funny, but I would appreciate some insightful input.

Comment: It'd be a good idea to clarify what you mean.  For example, your question title could be adjusted to "Where can I download matches", not "Where can I download a game" since that seems to suggest you haven't downloaded CS:GO yet.

Comment: Good edit I'd think. I just remember being able to right-click and download a match from "Your matches", but now it is not an option. Can I not download an old match?

Comment: I believe demos are only stored for a short time period, between 2 weeks to a month if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate, but some matches you play will not actually let you download a demo and only allow you to view the scoreboard, yet some matches will allow you to download demos.

I don't have anything authoratative to back this up, but I will speak for personal anecdote.

I found that by downloading matches immediately after finishing them, I could access them even if they were from months back, and re-download the match demo.  Unfortunately, if I never actually got around to downloading a demo, CS:GO would remove that option, and only allow me to see the scoreboard. Example below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that once you have downloaded a file it is downloaded on your system (locally). That is why you could access them even "months back".