# Can I download a demo that is not in the list anymore?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I forgot to download a demo of a match on de_cache that I did really well in, now I've played enough matches that it's not in the "Your Matches" tab anymore:

[image: Your Matches tab]

As you can see, there's not an arrow to view matches before either.  Is there a way to get that demo or is that match lost in the abyss?

Answer (score 1):

By my guesstimation that demo is gone forever. The Recent Matches tab displays demoes stored on a cloud, and most probably they are simply popped/deleted from the list as it overflows - Would be costly to allow an unlimited amount of storage space per user.

Your best bet would be to contact valve. I had no luck figuring out what they system entailed through google.

EDIT: It would seem that the .dem files might be time-based stored, not just popped when > num. 
Read more: [How can I get a match demo that I can't download?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172003/how-can-i-get-a-match-demo-that-i-cant-download)

Might be that they do both! But if it's time-based, it could be possible if you contact valve that it is still in their systems and that they could give it to you.